# Mapstruct Mapping both child class and parent as source

Tags: java, mapstruct

Currently writing some interceptor that coverts some request models into another model. I have mappings for all my different type of requests however since it is at the interceptor level I get a java Object for the request model. I added a mapping for Object so that I could just pass the Object that I get in the interceptor rather than casting it to one of the types that I have a mapping for, however, it doesn't work, it is not mapping any field. Interesting enough, somehow when I was messing around with the order of definition of my mappings, it worked, however it is not consistent, so I am not sure how I got it to work.

```
   @Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "myField", target = "myOtherField")
})
NiceModel toLoggableEntity(RequestModel1 request);

  @Mappings({
    @Mapping(source = "myField2", target = "myOtherField")
})
NiceModel toLoggableEntity(RequestModel2 request);

//so that I can pass Object from the interceptor without having 
//to figure out which request model to cast it to  
NiceModel toLoggableEntity(Object request);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not possible

but you can make your implementation in your mapping class

```
public abstract class MyMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "myField", target = "myOtherField")
    })
    abstract NiceModel toLoggableEntity(RequestModel1 request);

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "myField2", target = "myOtherField")
    })
    abstract NiceModel toLoggableEntity(RequestModel2 request);

    NiceModel toLoggableEntity(Object request) {
        if (request instanceof RequestModel1) {
            return toLoggableEntity((RequestModel1) request);
        }
        if (request instanceof RequestModel2) {
            return toLoggableEntity((RequestModel2) request);
        }
        //manage this case
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a work around. However, it would be ideal if the mapping would use the most specific mapping.

Comment: @Paul Look at issue [#131](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131) in Mapstruct's bugtracker. This is not directly possible, you'll only get workarounds. And the one presented here is the most commonly used one.

Comment: Regarding the answer: `MyMapper` can still be an interface if you implement `toLoggableEntity` as an [interface default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html).